# undefined method 'clearChildren' rhodes 4.0

Tags: android, ruby, rhomobile, rhodes

Just upgraded my project from rhodes 3.4.2 to rhodes 4.0.0--------------------------------
**sdk that I'm using: android-sdk-19,
ndk: android-ndk-r9b,
jdk: 1.7.0_25,
RMS version 4.0**

My build for android fails with the following error:
I 09/11/2014 19:13:02:836 00000dbc                  APP| App error: undefined method `clearChildren' for AppSys::AppSysEntitySchema:Module
 C:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-4.0.0/lib/framework/rho/rhocontroller.rb:121:in`serve'

All my paths are set correctly.Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There's any special reason to upgrade to v4.0 instead of the latest v5.0?

Comment: Yup.To avail the grayscale feature in camera mode.

Comment: I don't get exactly. Is this something not available in v5.0? Nevertheless, you're using an SDK and NDK released way after the RhoMobile 4.0 launch, try to use a newer rhodes gem or build it from github sources (use 4-0-stable branch)

Comment: Tried to build in RMS 2.2 as well, it gives the same thing.Tried with android-sdk 14 where rhosimulator runs properly, but the build fails with java annotation error.